# Topoengine Error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, route

By using closest facility in ArcMap, I found closest path between 78 points. Now, I am trying to split this route at intersection points by using feature to line management tool.

However, I have a topoengine error :

Error 999999: Error executing function. Invalid Topology[Topoengine error]. Failed to execute.

What I have tried is that :

1. I used repair geometry.
2. I used check geometry.
3. I unchecked background processing from geoprocessing option.
4. I copied the data to new file geodatabase.

But, I could not fix the problem. Do you have any suggestion to me ?

[image]

Comment: Try dissolve to single part lines.

Comment: Thanks, I have used multiparttoSinglepart_management tool but did not work. @FelixIP

Comment: Dissolve tool has nothing to do with what you did.

Comment: I have used dissolve_management to have single part then I used featuretoline_management, I have again topoengine error. Do you have any other suggestion to me ?

Comment: Why feature to line? Dissolve should give you perfect network.

Comment: Because, I want to see which CSD coordinates are using which segments to arrive their destination point. After splitting line at their intersection points, I can observe which segments are used by more than once. @FelixIP

Comment: Why dissolve is giving perfect network ? @FelixIP